# Ctrl + B bevel not beveling from center of edge

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, edges, bevel

I remember solving this issue by changing the origin once or something, but now I don't remember what to do

[image: the edge] and when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, it offsets the bevel
[image: edge beveled]

Comment: are you talking about applying the scale in Object mode?

Comment: You can include images here just fine, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Did you apply scale?

Comment: did you find a solution? I tried to reset the scale but still I would get a weird bevel... Also I don't have the below situation of an already beveled edge. I simply extruded some parts and I get these weirdly scaled bevels...

Comment: Well, wrong! I did reset the scale by applying ctrl + a to have a scale of 1,1,1 again. and then I would use the bevel with `Width Type` = `Offset` and this would give me the wanted result. You maybe try this...

Answer (score 1):

You look to be making a bevel of an already beveled edge, which isn't the same thing as beveling the two connected edges simultaneously. (That's probably the way to go.) If you want the two edges to be beveled to different widths, while containing the topology at the corner, you could do that with a Bevel modifier, by weight, and adjust the edge bevel weights, keeping an eye on the resulting topology. (Temporarily check 'Wire' and 'All Edges' in the object's display settings.)